# Approaching sound index by multiplying second and sample rate isn't accurate

Tags: audio, indexing, sample-rate

I was experimenting sounds and I thought that seconds multiplied by sample rate would give me the correct index on the sound. But when I tested out, it actually turned out that it is faster then it should on short sounds and slower on the long sounds. Which approach have I thought wrong? Or is it caused by the other reasons?

Comment: Sounds like a rounding problem to me. Without the specific sample number, sample rate, seconds value and calculated answer it is going to be hard to give more information

Comment: @fdapp I am currently getting audio index by `round(sec*SAMPLERATE)`

Comment: `floor(seconds * samplerate)`

Comment: Technically `trunc` rather than `floor`, but `floor` with be fine

Comment: Well it is still not working, but I found that the number of data divided by the sample rate does not match with the length of the audio. I think it is different problem.

Comment: I found that it was problem with channels. It is fixed now. Thank you for trying to help me